# Chatbot integration in SharePoint Online Site. Chatbot created using MERN

Tags: sharepoint, chatbot, sharepoint-online, openai-api, spfx

Hello SharePoint Online Community. Please help me, I have a SharePoint online communication site and I want to integrate a chat bot in it.. So the challenge I am facing is chat bot is created using MERN. Is there any possibility to add this chatbot to my SharePoint site? How we can use SPFx for it?

Please give any solution.
Thank you

I want to integrate ChatBot created in MERN in SharePoint online communication site using SPFx.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a MERN app in SharePoint is an interesting proof of concept, but I don't think it would be possible to implement express straight out of the box in SPFx as it seems it's mainly a frontend framework.

I recommend looking into the suit of tools Azure offers and try to replace express with those. For example make API calls to a azure function/logic app which would handle communicating with mongoDB.